# Return table count from a function in which the table is a parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to be able to get the count from various tables using a function.

Here's what I have right now:

```
IF EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE ID = OBJECT_ID(N'getTableCount')
    AND XTYPE IN (N'FN', N'IF', N'TF')
)
    DROP FUNCTION getTableCount
GO

CREATE FUNCTION getTableCount (@tableName VARCHAR(255))
RETURNS INT
AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @count INT;
        DECLARE @getCountQuery VARCHAR(255) = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' + @tableName;

        SET @count = EXEC @getCountQuery;

        RETURN @count;
    END
```

I know this doesn't work. `RETURN` has a red squiggly with the message `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'EXEC'.`

So how do I accomplish that?

Also, to use the function in a calculation would this be the correct usage?

```
SELECT 2000 - dbo.getTableCount
```

That's purely an example, but represents how I need to use the function.

Comment: You can't in a function. Functions can't use the `EXEC` statement. This could only be achieved by a fully dynamic statement.

Comment: To count the rows at runtime, you would need dynamic SQL - which isn't possible in a function.  But you can get it from metadata - e.g. `sys.dm_db_partition_stats`

Comment: *Also, syntax like `SET @count = EXEC @getCountQuery;` (which is actually invalid, it would be `EXEC (@getCountQuery)`) is a bad idea. You should be using `OUTPUT` parameters with `sp_executesql`.*

Comment: Aside: The best practice when assembling object names into dynamic SQL statements is to use [`QuoteName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql) to avoid problems with odd names, e.g. `New Table` with a space or reserved words like `From`.

Comment: Plus the high risk of injection with unquoted, and unchecked, dynamic strings, @HABO :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, it's impossible to do it the way you expect to. However, there's a more efficient way to achieve this by querying system views.

```
CREATE FUNCTION getTableCount (@tableName VARCHAR(255))
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN

    RETURN (    SELECT SUM(row_count) tableCount
                FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats p
                JOIN sys.tables t ON p.object_id = t.object_id
                WHERE index_id <= 1 --Just clustered index or heap
                AND t.name = PARSENAME( @tableName, 1)
                AND (t.schema_id = SCHEMA_ID(PARSENAME( @tableName, 2)) OR PARSENAME( @tableName, 2) IS NULL));
END
```

Now, if we're talking about efficient ways to code, we could simply convert this into an inline table-valued function that will run several times faster.

```
CREATE FUNCTION getTableCount (@tableName VARCHAR(255))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN SELECT SUM(row_count) TableCount
        FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats p
        JOIN sys.tables t ON p.object_id = t.object_id
        WHERE index_id <= 1 --Just clustered index or heap
        AND t.name = PARSENAME( @tableName, 1)
        AND (t.schema_id = SCHEMA_ID(PARSENAME( @tableName, 2)) OR PARSENAME( @tableName, 2) IS NULL);
```

Comment: Note that the metadata info is an ***approximate*** of the row count and might differ slightly from the actual row count.

Comment: If the data is changing constantly, the row count using COUNT(*) will also be approximate. Both options represent an exact count at a certain point in time. Most of the times, people use this counts to check if a table is empty or to validate a load. In both of these cases, the results are going to be consistent.