# Apply function to a list of tables and columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, dry

I want to count the rows in a table, and the rows that satisfy a condition, for each table in a set of tables, by date. Each table's date column goes by a different name.

A simple way of achieving this is:

```
SELECT 'TableA' AS 'TableName', [AsOfDate], COUNT(*) AS 'Rowcount', SUM(IIF([X] IS NULL,0,1)) AS 'NonEmpty'
FROM TableA GROUP BY [AsOfDate]
UNION ALL
SELECT 'TableB' AS 'TableName', [Snapshot Date], COUNT(*) AS 'Rowcount', SUM(IIF([X] IS NULL,0,1)) AS 'NonEmpty'
FROM TableB GROUP BY [Snapshot Date]
...UNION ALL {TableC,D,E...}
```

How can I accomplish the above starting with a table of table names and pertinent columns? Like this:

```
WITH Tables AS ( SELECT * FROM ( VALUES
    ('TableA', 'AsOfDate'),
    ('TableB', 'Snapshot Date'),
...
    ('TableZ', 'Date of Record')
) AS (Tables([Table],[DateColumn]) )
SELECT MyFn([Table],[DateColumn]) FROM Tables
```

Yielding

```
[Table]    [Date]    [Rows]    [NonEmpty]
TableA     2022-01-01    20    18
TableA     2022-01-02    20    19
TableA     2022-01-03    20     0
TableB     2022-01-01    30    28
...
```

I thought executing dynamic SQL in a function taking the table name and column name would do the trick, but [apparently that's not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55633448/return-table-count-from-a-function-in-which-the-table-is-a-parameter#comment97958137_55633448). What's a DRY solution?

Comment: Dynamic SQL is the answer as you've already established, but you'll need to dynamically generate the entire unioned set of statements using `sys.tables` and `sys.columns`. How do you know which column is the required date column in each table?

Comment: You can't use a function here as this is going to require dynamic and dynamic sql is not allowed in a function. What is "Non Empty" in your output?

Comment: @Stu, the required date column is inlined along with the table name (TableA, AsOfDate),(TableB, SnapshotDate)...

Comment: @SeanLange [Non Empty] is just what I call the sum of (IIF([X] IS NULL, 0,1)) in the UNION version, where [X] is just another column in TableA, TableB etc. that's of interest.

Comment: I just learned about sqlcmd scripting variables. They can help accomplish similar objectives.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/scripting/sqlcmd-use-with-scripting-variables?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of a simple way to construct your dynamic SQL using *string_agg* based on your supplied table of names/column(s), provided you're using a recent (V14+) version of SQL Server. Just follow the same pattern to add additional columns...

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max);
with t as ( 
    select n, d from (
        values 
          ('TableA', 'AsOfDate'),
          ('TableB', 'Snapshot Date'),
          ('Tablez', 'date of Record')
    )v(n, d)
)
select 
    @sql =
    String_Agg(
    Concat(
        'Select ''', n, ''' as TableName, ',
        QuoteName(d), ', Count(*) as rowcount from ',
        QuoteName(n), ' group by ', 
        QuoteName(d)
        ), Concat(' union all', Char(13))
    )
from t;

print @sql;
```

Output:

```
Select 'TableA' as TableName, [AsOfDate], Count(*) as rowcount from [TableA] group by [AsOfDate] union all
Select 'TableB' as TableName, [Snapshot Date], Count(*) as rowcount from [TableB] group by [Snapshot Date] union all
Select 'Tablez' as TableName, [date of Record], Count(*) as rowcount from [Tablez] group by [date of Record]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way you can do this. I know that most people would go to a cursor or while loop but it really isn't needed. Since your sample data didn't have the column X, I left that off and will let you figure that part out. Given the table names and the date column something like this should be close. If your date columns are datetime columns you may have to convert them to a date do the grouping works as expected.

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = '';

with cte as
(
    SELECT * FROM 
    ( VALUES
        ('TableA', 'AsOfDate'),
        ('TableB', 'Snapshot Date'),
        ('TableZ', 'Date of Record')
    ) x(TableName, DateColumn)
)
select @sql = string_agg('select TableName = ' + quotename(c.TableName, '''') + ', MyDate = ' + quotename(c.DateColumn) + ', count(*) from ' + quotename(c.TableName) + ' group by ' + quotename(c.DateColumn), ' union all ')
from cte c
    
--use this to view the dynamic sql created
select @sql

--once you are satisfied the dynamic is accurate uncomment the line below to execute it
--exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: Do not use `set @variable += ...` with multiple rows, it has undefined behaviour, see https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/132709/220697 etc. Use `STRING_AGG` or `FOR XML` instead. Also you should do `'select TableName = ' + quotename(c.TableName, '''') + ', MyDate =` to quote the table name with apostrophes `'`

Comment: Thanks for the edits @Charlieface. I know better than using a variable like that but old habits die hard. ;)

Answer (score 0):

The `STRING_AGG` answers didn't work for me because I'm stuck with SQL Server 2016, but they did help me search for and find an older syntax that works:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
WITH
CTE_TableName AS (
    SELECT 0 AS Field0, TableName, DateColumn
    FROM ( VALUES
    ('TableA','AsOfDate'),
    ('TableB','Snapshot Date'),
    ('TableZ','EFFDATE')
    ) x(TableName, DateColumn)
),
SqlConcat AS (SELECT TOP 1 (
    SELECT 'SELECT ' + QUOTENAME(t1.TableName,'''') + ' AS ''TableName'', ' + QUOTENAME(t1.DateColumn,'[]') + ' AS ''Date'','
    + 'COUNT(*) AS ''Rows'','
    + 'SUM(IIF(COALESCE(CommonColumnA, CommonColumnZ) IS NULL,0,1)) AS ''HasValue'''
    + ' FROM ' + QUOTENAME(t1.TableName,'[]')
    + ' GROUP BY ' + QUOTENAME(t1.DateColumn,'[]')
    + ' UNION ALL '
        FROM CTE_TableName t1
        WHERE t1.Field0 = t0.Field0
        FOR XML PATH('')) AS SqlConcat
    FROM CTE_TableName t0
GROUP BY t0.Field0, t0.TableName, t0.DateColumn
)
SELECT @SQL = (
    'WITH dateRange as (
    SELECT CAST(DATEADD(DAY, -35, GETDATE()) AS DATE) AS ''Date''
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY,1,[Date])
    FROM dateRange
    WHERE DATEADD(DAY,1,[Date]) < GETDATE()
    )' +
    'SELECT [TableName], dateRange.[Date], [Rows], [HasValue] FROM (' + 
    --Trim the final 'UNION ALL'
    (SELECT LEFT(SqlConcat, LEN(SqlConcat)-9) FROM SqlConcat) + 
    ') AS QrySql RIGHT JOIN dateRange ON QrySQL.[Date] = dateRange.[Date] WHERE NOT [TableName] IS NULL' +
    'ORDER BY [TableName], [Date] DESC'
) 
--SELECT @SQL
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
```

Comment: Yes prior to SQL Server 2017 using the `for xml path` accomplishes the same thing in principle, just a bit more cludgy.